# how to map flux stopping if async condition is satisfied?

Tags: java, asynchronous, project-reactor, flatmap

consider i have a flux of integers and this method simulating an async external api data retrieval, which can return an empty response for some specific unknown input:

```
public static Mono<String> getApiData(int i) {
    if (i == 3) return Mono.empty(); // i'm using 3 just as an example
    return Mono.just(String.valueOf(i * 2));
}
```

and these methods to be executed with `getApiData` output, depending on the result:

```
// when getApiData returns non empty mono
public static Mono<Boolean> updateDatabaseWithApiData(int apiInput, String apiOutput) {
    System.out.println(apiInput + " -> " + apiOutput);
    // lots of unrelated logic
    return Mono.just(true);
}

// when getApiData returns empty mono
public static Mono<Boolean> logFailure(int apiInput) {
    System.out.println(apiInput + " -> failure");
    // registering errors logs
    return Mono.just(false);
}
```

with this i would like to write a method like this `Mono<Boolean> processFluxUntilFailure(Flux<Integer> flux)` that applies `getApiData` for each element and **stops when a failure occurs**. then if at least a single element reaches `updateDatabaseWithApiData`, return `Mono.just(true)`, `Mono.just(false)` otherwise.

so i would get this output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    processFluxUntilFailure(flux).subscribe(value -> System.out.println("result " + value));
}
```

desired output:

```
1 -> 2
2 -> 4
3 -> failure
result true
```

since we had (at least 1) 2 successful elements processed.

considering:

- this is a simplified version of my real problem
- i can't predict when data will be empty from `getApiData`
- i can't change the described methods, only `processFluxUntilFailure`

i tried this:

```
public static Mono<Boolean> processFluxUntilFailure(Flux<Integer> flux) {
    return flux.flatMap(apiInput -> getApiData(apiInput)
                    .flatMap(apiOutput -> updateDatabaseWithApiData(apiInput, apiOutput))
                    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> logFailure(apiInput)))
            )
            .reduce((b1, b2) -> b1 || b2);
}
```

which resulted in

```
1 -> 2
2 -> 4
3 -> failure
4 -> 8
5 -> 10
result true
```

how can i achieve my desired output from this try? in other words, how can i "stop" `flatMap` if some async condition is satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [takeWhile](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-) for this use-case.

*takeWhile* short your flow execution upon receiving an "invalid value", i.e once it fails a certain test/predicate. As it does *not* include the failed element in the output (contrary to *takeUntil*), it should match your requirement.

So, your function could be expressed like that:

```java
public static Mono<Boolean> processFluxUntilFailure(Flux<Integer> flux) {
    return flux.flatMap(apiInput -> getApiData(apiInput)
                    .flatMap(apiOutput -> updateDatabaseWithApiData(apiInput, apiOutput))
                    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> logFailure(apiInput)))
            )
            .takeWhile(Boolean.TRUE::equals)
            .last(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm open if there's any less verbose ways:

```
public static Mono<Boolean> processFluxUntilFailure(Flux<Integer> flux) {
    return flux

            .flatMap(apiInput -> getApiData(apiInput)
                    .flatMap(apiOutput -> updateDatabaseWithApiData(apiInput, apiOutput))
                    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> logFailure(apiInput)))
            ).<Boolean>handle((b, sink) -> {
                if (b) sink.next(true);
                else sink.complete();
            })

            .defaultIfEmpty(false)
            .reduce((b1, b2) -> b1 || b2);
}
```

got me this output:

```
1 -> 2
2 -> 4
3 -> failure
result true
```

apparently `flatMap` and `handle` are not eager evaluated and putting them together did the trick